# OpenGl 3.3 Error resurfaced with Blender 2.8 Final release

Tags: gpu, error

On my Windows10-64bit laptop (IntelHd 3000 Gpu - Opengl3.1 support) ,I was initially not able to run Blender 2.8 beta(zip) , but could run it on using this Opengl32.dll file found [here](https://fdossena.com/?p=mesa/index.frag)

But now with 2.8 final version the Opengl error resurfaces , also when used with the above mentioned "Opengl32.dll "file .(All Gpu drivers are up to date).

Also, tried using this command line option but the error persists-

```
 .\blender.exe --debug -gpu
```

Any suggestion would be really help full.

[Opengl3.3 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15MdA.jpg)

Comment: What is the error? Is there a message at all?

Comment: I have attached the command line error image (Opengl3.3 Error)

Answer (score 2):

Blender 2.8 **requires** OpenGL 3.3 or above. Your computer does not meet the requirements and as such, Blender 2.8 will not run on it.

Using random DLLs from the internet is generally not a good idea, especially with programs as demanding as Blender.